# php algorithm sorting a set of data into groups of no more than four

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I currently have the problem that I have a dataset of about **1000** entries.

Each entry has two relevant features:

- `weight` (float)
- `origin` (string / another entity)

I have to sort those entries into groups of max. four entries. Groups can contain less entries, though.

- group of four entries: very good
- group of three entries: good
- group of two entries: not so good
- group of one entry: really bad (but possible if not avoidable)

Now, the way those entries are being sorted into the groups depend on their features in the following way:

- the max. delta of `weight` within a group can be **10%**.
- there should be as many different values for `origin` as possible in each group. Having one duplicate is not so bad, but having three or more entries with the same `origin` should be avoided.

Within the dataset `weight` has a range of roughly **20.0** to **120.0**.
There are about **50** different possible values for `origin`.

I have to implement this in php, but answering with a php implementation is not necessary. The algorithm alone would be enough.

I have tried sorting all values for their `weight` and then simply split them every fourth entry. But the groups I then get are hard to rearrange with regard to the `origin` value. I think I could somehow get this done through a nasty implementation, but I hope there is a very elegant algorithm that can do just that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us what have you tryied. If you expect someone here to write the code for you, you are on the wrong site.

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou I really dont expect the code, I need an algorithm or at least an idea for an algorithm to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a greedy that might give good results:

```
Sort entried by weight
groups = []
used = array of length len(entries) initialized in false    
For i = 0 to len(entries):
    if (used[i] == false):
        group = [entries[i]]
        j = i + 1
        while(j < len(entries) and delta(group[0], entries[j]) < 10 and len(group) < 4):
           if used[j] == false and entries[j].origin != all the origins in group:
               group.add(entries[j])
               used[j] = true
           j = j + 1
        if (len(group) < 4):
            //decide if you prefer a small group or a bigger group with repeated origins
        groups.add(group)
```

Comment: thx i will look into this algo. just one thing: where does `j` come from?

Comment: @Micha seems I fotgot to initialize it, updated. J is just a pointer for the next elements of i